# How to upsample a MultiIndex DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a `MultiIndex` `DataFrame` with a `DateTimeIndex` at one of the levels.

```
dates = pandas.date_range('20180101', periods=10)
index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, list('ABC')])
df    = pandas.DataFrame(index=index, 
                         columns=list('1234'), 
                         data=numpy.random.randn(30,4))
```

I would like to upsample this to minutely, forward filling.

I have found the following methods

```
df.unstack().resample('T').ffill().stack()

df = df.groupby(pandas.Grouper(freq='T', level=0)).ffill()
```

However, both are very memory intensive, and with my dataset I am getting a `MemoryError`.

Prior to its deprecation I could represent my dataset using a `Panel`, with one `DataFrame` per date

```
pnl  = pandas.Panel(items=dates, 
                    major_axis=list('ABC'), 
                    minor_axis=list('1234'), 
                    data=numpy.random.rand(120).reshape(10,3,4))
```

Upsampling a panel is dead easy:

```
pnl = pnl.resample('T').ffill()
```

**How can I upsample my `MultiIndex DataFrame` in a memory efficient manor?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, how big is your dataframe (how many days are there, and how many columns) ?

Comment: As a panel: `Dimensions: 2568 (items) x 7 (major_axis) x 7 (minor_axis)` - So that's 2568 days, each with 7 rows x 7 columns

Comment: So the final dataframe should have a size of at least `24 * 60 * 2568 * 7 * 7 * 8 / 1024**3` which is around 1.3 Gb (assuming most of the data are float). How much storage does your RAM have ?

Comment: @Zuma I've got 16GB. When I run the resample operation on the dataframe I can see memory usage increase over time until my machine starts swapping like crazy and eventually a `MemoryError` is thrown

Comment: It seems weird to me that all 16 Gb of your RAM are used by this. The only other option I see is to split your dataframe in chunks, do the up sampling on the chunks and then merge them back